# Obtener determinados campos de endpoint personalizado en colección de usuarios - Strapi

Tags: strapi

soy nuevo en Strapi, y estaba personalizando el backend, estoy intentando crear un endpoint personalizado que te devuelva sólo algunos campos del usuario. Después de crear el [endpoint personalizado](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#controllers) llamado getUsername, tengo el sgte código:

Dentro de la carpeta api se crea /controllers/user.js

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  async getUsername(ctx) {
  const { username } = ctx.params;
    const user = await strapi.query("user", "users-permissions").find({ username })
    return user;
  }
};
```

Y en esa misma, se crea también /config/routes.json

```js
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/user/:username",
      "handler": "user.getUsername",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Entonces usando Postman o haciendo una petición a ${URL_de_la_api}/user/{nombre_de_usuario}, puedo obtener el usuario dependiendo de su username. Ahora, esto me devuelve un obj muy largo, no quiero obtener todas las propiedades sino algunas, sólo el id, name y username. He creado un tema parecido en los foros de Strapi, pero parece que está muerto, nada de gente, o si la hay, no te toman interés, sin respuesta alguna. Entonces cómo podría obtener sólo esos 3 campos en la respuesta del servidor?.

Mi base de datos es mongoDB y si mal no recuerdo se usaba db.nombredelacoleccion.findOne({ username: 'Husdady' }, { username: 1 }). Parece que en Strapi no funciona así, alguien que sepa Strapi que me ayude?